# python3: UTF-8 encoding in http.server

Tags: python-3.x, utf-8, httpserver

I have encoding problems when serving a simple web page in python3, using BaseHTTPRequestHandler.

Here is a working example:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*

from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer
from os import curdir, sep, remove
import cgi

HTML_FILE_NAME = 'test.html'
PORT_NUMBER = 8080

# This class will handles any incoming request from the browser
class myHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):

    # Handler for the GET requests
    def do_GET(self):
        self.path = HTML_FILE_NAME
        try:
            with open(curdir + sep + self.path, 'r') as f:
                self.send_response(200)
                self.send_header('Content-type', 'text/html')
                self.end_headers()
                self.wfile.write(bytes(f.read(), 'UTF-8'))
            return
        except IOError:
            self.send_error(404, 'File Not Found: %s' % self.path)

try:
    # Create a web server and define the handler to manage the incoming request
    with open(HTML_FILE_NAME, 'w') as f:
        f.write('<!DOCTYPE html><html><body> <p> My name is Jérôme </p> </body></html>')
    print('Started httpserver on port %i.' % PORT_NUMBER)

    #Wait forever for incoming http requests
    HTTPServer(('', PORT_NUMBER), myHandler).serve_forever()

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print('Interrupted by the user - shutting down the web server.')
    server.socket.close()
    remove(HTML_FILE_NAME)
```

The expected result is to serve a web page displaying *My name is Jérôme*.

Instead, I have: *My name is JÃ©rÃ´me*

As you can see, the html page is correctly encoded, with `self.wfile.write(bytes(f.read(), 'UTF-8'))`, so I think the problem comes from the web server.

How to tell the web server to serve the page in UTF-8?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No problem if I add:

```
<meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
<meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding">
```

in my html head.

Comment: use header is better for instance source code like .js can't have <meta tag>

Answer (score 11):

Your web server is already sending the text encoded to UTF-8 but you need to tell your browser the encoding of the bytes it receives. The HTTP spec. declares ISO-8995-1 as the default.

The HTTP standard way of doing is this is to tag the `Content-type` header value with a `charset` sub-key.

Therefore, you should change your code to read:

```
self.send_header('Content-type', 'text/html; charset=utf-8')
```

Also, watch out for the encoding of your HTML file. Without an [encoding given to `open()`](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html#reading-and-writing-unicode-data), it'll be guessed based on your locale. This won't break anything, unless you end up running this script where the locale is `C`, `POSIX` or non-latin Windows.

Comment: the ***Also** hint saved my day, I added a reference :)